# UITableView tableHeaderView not painting in SDK 3.0

Tags: iphone, uitableview, header

I am writing an iphone app.  I use a UITableView and assign a my UIView derived class to the tableHeaderView property.  When I build with SDK 3.1 the header displays properly.  When I build with 3.0 the header is never painted.  DrawRect is not called.

Is this a known SDK bug, or am I doing something wrong?  The only thing that changes this table's appearance is changing the SDK version.

Thanks,

Comment: If there is a bug, it would be in your derived class. Are you able to add your UIView class as a subview to another UIViewController under 3.0?

Comment: You were right.  Some draw flags were set so that it rendered with 3.1 but not 3.0
If you post an answer I'll give you the checkmark.