# Custom UITableView headerView disappears after memory warning

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios, uitableview

I have a `UITableViewController`. I create a custom headerView for it's `tableView` in the `loadView` method like so:

```
(void)loadView {
    [super loadView];

    UIView* containerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height * 2 )];  
    containerView.tag = 'cont';
    containerView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin;

    UIButton* button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    button.frame = CGRectMake(padding, height, width, height);
    ... //configure UIButton and events

    UIImageView* imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"] highlightedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"highlight.png"]];    
    imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height );
    ... //configure UIImageView

    [containerView addSubview:button];
    [containerView addSubview:imageView];
    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = containerView;

    [imageView release];
    [containerView release];
}
```

None of the other methods (viewDidLoad/Unload, etc) are overloaded.

This controller is hosted in a tab. When I switch to another tab and simulate a memory warning, and then come back to this tab, my `UITableView` is missing my custon header. All the rows/section are visible as I would expect. Putting a BP in the `loadView` code above, I see it being invoked when I switch back to the tab after the memory warning, and yet I can't actually see the header.

Any ideas about what I'm missing here?

EDIT: This happens on the device and the simulator. On the device, I just let a memory warning occur by opening a bunch of different apps while mine is in the background.

Comment: I guess you have code in your viewDidUnload() method like this: self.tableView.tableHeaderView = nil; ?

Comment: No. "None of the other methods (viewDidLoad/Unload, etc) are overloaded". Do I need it? Why?

Comment: Confused. Hope someone else can help.

Comment: This behaviour is pretty odd, since if you did not overload "didReciveMemoryWarning", your UiTableViewController should unload itself as well. It would reload the next time you open the tab and so would your headers. Just for my curiosity: What happens when you add didReciveMemoryWarning{ [super didReciveMemoryWarning]... to your class. Or is it already there?

Comment: @Phlibbo tried that, no difference. It wasn't already there.

Comment: This code should go in viewDidLoad, and not in loadView

Comment: Has `self.tableView` been set when `-loadView` is called after a memory warning? How about `self.view`?

Comment: @Eiko, why do you say "should"? AFAICT there's nothing wrong with how I have it. If this was wrong it would not work regardless of memory warning. @JoostK, yes both are.

Comment: @psychotik In loadView - if implemented - you should set up a view and assign this to the controller's view. Every further setup should go in loadDidView. And calling super's implementation makes rarely sense in those cases. Work with the frameworks and not against them. It will pay off. How is your loadDidView method looking if you have one, and the viewDidUnload?

Answer (score 6):

the loadView method shouldn't call super. Try removing [super loadView]; and that may well solve your problem. The other overridden view methods (viewDidLoad, viewWillAppear etc.) can call super just fine.  See the documentation at:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html

for confirmation.

Comment: It states explictly in loadView: "Your custom implementation of this method should not call super"

Comment: Interestingly, the UITableViewController class reference states, "You may override loadView or any other superclass method, but if you do be sure to invoke the superclass implementation of the method, usually as the first method call."

Comment: Bounty got auto-awarded. This isn't the fix.

Answer (score 2):

Keep containView instead of releasing it.  And return it in tableView:viewForHeaderInSection: (UITableViewDelegate method).

Comment: What's wrong with releasing it? `tableHeaderView` retains it. Regardless, `loadView` is being invoked when I move back to this tab so I don't understand why it works initially but not after a mem warning.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem to this, though it doesn't seem to explain the OP's situation based on his code; I just want to put it here in case anyone else comes across this.

I retain my header view in an instance variable. In my viewDidLoad I check to see if this variable is nil, if it is then I create the view, retain and set the instance variable to it and set `tableHeaderView` to it. The problem is that this condition will only be true once, because my instance variable will never be nil after the first time I create it; however, the table view's `tableHeaderView` property *will* be set to nil when there's a memory warning, so there won't be a header view any more, even though I still have the view in an instance variable.

The solution was either to change the check to see if the table view's `tableHeaderView`'s property is nil (and then re-create the header view every time that gets set to nil), or (since in this case I still have the view retained in an instance variable) to move the assignment to `tableHeaderView` outside of the if-block, thus every time `viewDidLoad` is run, we will make sure to re-assign the header view to `tableHeaderView` in case it got set to nil.

Comment: +1 @psychotik In terms of application flow, it's better to have the `headerView` code in `viewDidLoad` rather than `loadView`: `loadView` is supposed to do simply that, upon return `self.view` is set. Once `loadView` returns, `viewDidLoad` is called on the controller class, which is where you can set additional properties. I would say implement the header view setting in `viewDidLoad`, and clear it in `viewDidUnload`.

Answer (score 0):

What are width and height? Is it possible that they are zero after a memory warning?

Comment: Good thought -- I verified that they are valid after the memory warning.

Answer (score 0):

that is normal way, iOS use this way to reduce memory, while receive memory issue, then it will free some UI element , that also will invoke method 'didUnLoad' ... you have to free the headerView in the method 'didUnLoad' , set to nil , and then in the method 'didLoad' to create the headerView if it is nil and then add it to tableView as well....
 iOS will automatic free some UI elements while face memory warning .

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into a similar issue that was causing my custom header for the uitableview to not be reloaded after receiving a memory warning. my current implementation to create the header is

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    if (_tableHeaderView == nil)
    {
        [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"DetailHeaderView" owner:self options:nil];
        self.tableView.tableHeaderView = _tableHeaderView;
    }
}
```

and to fix the problem i simply added this line to my didReceiveMemoryWarning

```
_tableHeaderView = nil
```

and now it is reloading after a memory warning is sent.
Sorry if this has already been answered but I didn't see a clear cut answer for my problem and figured I'd pop this in here for anyone else in my situation.

Happy Coding

Answer (score -1):

Doing a reloadData on the table view might help

Comment: Hey, thanks for the -1 votes, but I have in the past seen mostly-correct tableviews lose their headers, only to be solved by doing a table reload.

Answer (score -2):

The only problem that I can see by looking at just your `loadView` is that you are trying to tag your `containerView` with a string. That should be an `NSInteger` as far as I know.

Comment: That's not a string. Notice the single quotes.

Comment: It is not an `NSString` but it is a char *, no? The tag property expects an `NSInteger`.

Comment: No. char * is still declared with double quotes. That's a 32-bit int value, defined as sequential chars. I assure you it's valid, and not related to this problem.

Answer (score -2):

This problem is known. For example, if you use the TableViewDelegate `tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:` it won't work, too.

The problem is iOS and not you. There aren't many questions about the tableHeaderView because nobody use it, and so Apple didn't get any BugTracker entries...

Have a look to a older question: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1868551/uitableview-tableheaderview-not-painting-in-sdk-3-0). And [here](https://discussions.apple.com/message/8706109) are other problems.

So I think really it's a SDK bug...

Comment: What ^ said. Notice that this worked as expected until a memory warning, so I don't think there anything fundamentally wrong with how I'm building/assigning stuff to the View.